# Why HashMap resize when it hits TREEIFY_THRESHOLD value which is not required?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

**I know How HashMap works internally**. But while checking HashMap code with TreeNode implementation I'm not getting the goal behind the increasing size of bucket but not **treeify** until bucket size hits **MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64.**

**Note:** I've considered `Map m = new HashMap();` so default size would be 16.

Default values.

```
static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8;
static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64;
```

**HashMap#putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict)**

I extracted few lines from `putVal` method.

```
else {
    for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
        if ((e = p.next) == null) {
            p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
            if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1) // -1 for 1st
                treeifyBin(tab, hash);
            break;
        }
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            break;
        p = e;
    }
}
```

So whenever `binCount` hits 7 it'll call **treeifyBin(tab, hash);** Now lets follow the code in method `treeifyBin`.

**HashMap#treeifyBin(Node[] tab, int hash)**

```
final void treeifyBin(Node<K,V>[] tab, int hash) {
    int n, index; Node<K,V> e;
    if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) < MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY)
        resize();
    else if ((e = tab[index = (n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        TreeNode<K,V> hd = null, tl = null;
        ....
    }
}
```

**Why?**
Here in this method in first `IF` it checks that current `tab` size is less than `MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64` then call `resize()`. Which internally increase the `tab` size from default **16 to 32** and transfer all element to new **tab**. And again **32 to 64**. Which I think is overhead or unnecessarily.

So whats the goal behind this? Checking size with `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD` in `putVal` but not doing **treeify** until it hits `MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both, using a tree or a capacity larger than usual, are measures to deal with collisions. When there are multiple keys mapped to the same bucket, it can be one of the following scenarios (or a combination of them):

1. The keys have different hash codes but got mapped to the same bucket
2. The keys have the same hash code but implement `Comparable`
3. The keys have the same hash code and do not implement `Comparable`

Neither approach can deal with point three. Only building a tree can deal with the second. When we have the first scenario, expanding the table may solve the issue and if it does, it has the advantage of still providing an `O(1)` lookup and allowing more efficient traversal (just iterating over the array) whereas the tree has an `O(log n)` lookup and less efficient traversal, requiring to descend the tree structure.

The problem is, analyzing the scenario, to find out which solution is applicable and whether expanding the table would actually help, would take time on its own. Further, it wouldn’t pay off when a single `put` takes the expense of the analysis to dismiss a strategy, just to end up with the next `put` finding the strategy suitable for another key (after all, expanding the table size has an impact on the entire table).

So a heuristic is used to accommodate likelihoods and typical use cases of `HashMap`, incorporating not just a single `put` operation. Note that for small table sizes, the chances of solving a bucket collision via expansion are higher, a table size of 16 implies using only four bits of the hash code whereas a table size of 32 implies using five bits, 25% more.

I suppose, the JDK team used the usual approach of benchmarking real life applications and libraries to find the right trade-off.